# how to use sessions?

Tags: php, html, session

hello i have a question how to use sessions.

i would like to change the language of a site. so the logic of the language settings is the following:

when calling my site it will be checked, if there is a browser_accept_language.
if there is a language setting it will be used as a preferred language otherwise the default language is set.
in the next step it will be checked if there is already a setting for it stored in a session.
if there is a session value for language the preferred language will be changed to the session entry.

okay, that is the logic part. now i tried to code. the problem is that it seems not working and i have no clue why.

so the php is:

```
<?PHP       
    session_start();

    header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");


    include_once "scripts/db_connect.php";

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){
    $max   = 0.0;
    $languages = explode(",", (strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])));
    foreach($languages as $language){
        $language = explode(';', $language);
        $q    = (isset($language[1])) ? ((float) $language[1]) : 1.0;
        if ($q > $max){
            $max = $q;
            $pref_language = $language[0];
        }
    }
    $pref_language = trim($pref_language);
}

$_SESSION['language'] = $pref_language_changed;

if (isset ($_SESSION['language']) ){

    $pref_language = $pref_language_changed;

}...
```

followed by some html for mainwrapper the footer:

```
if ($pref_language === "af" OR $pref_language === "en"{
    $footer = "footer1";
    }else{
        $footer = "footer2";
    }

include_once "../scripts/".$footer.".php";
```

and the footer itself is:

```
        ... <ul class="flag">
                <li id="'.$language_flag.'">
                    <ul class="drop_down">
                        <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
                            <a href="/foo"><li id="one"><div>language1</div></li></a>
                            <a href="/bar"><li id="two"><div>language2</div></li></a>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>...
<!--Footer -->';    


if (isset($_POST['one'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = "language1";
    }
if (isset($_POST['two'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = "language2";
    }
?>
```

this is what all my pages are built of.

if there is someone who could tell me how to use sessions i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: **"not working"** well that's descriptive.

Comment: thanks for this competent answer!

Comment: @bonny it's still completely accurate. What exactly is your question?

Comment: start the session, add stuff to it and then purge it when your done

Comment: my answer (comment) is as competent as your (non existent) question.

Comment: ...who could tell me how to use sessions... would be great when you would learn reading ;) but this would be impossible for you, i guess.

Comment: *Ask a proper question.* What about the code above is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="drop_down">
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
        <li><input type="submit" name="one" value="language1"></li>
        <li id="two"><input type="submit" name="one" value="language2"></li>
    </form>
 </ul>
```

Also when you want to link an `<li>`
use

```
<li><a href="/foo">Link</a></li>
```

Dont use the a href outside the `<li>`

Comment: hello, i would like to have that link just to add the session value. is that not possible? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to relod page after submitting lang via POST, as you read new lang BEFORE it is loaded! Other option is to move the code which set session before it is actually checked.

Jeffreys answer also is right. Your original code wasnt sending lang at all.